# Blogger (BlogSpot): not open link and not change design

Tags: html, xml, hyperlink, blogger, blogspot

i'm learning creating template from scratch, but i crash with the next issue, like we know in html we create *.html files that has our design code, so i created this template http://tesety.blogspot.com/ my template is about music, the most simple way of categorizing music types. So i created the next code in a entrance and in page:

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #myInput {
        background-image: url(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/aLGnJhijsnc1qA-luOZiF6hsXFH7osaiVhthJf8Kt35FvecKGha7kbey-zbzbe-o0KSMEw=s400);
        background-position: 5px 5px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #232323;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 6px 5px 6px 10px;
    }

    #myInputBorde {
        border: 1px solid #ff9999;
        padding: 1px;
    }

    #myUL {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #myUL li a.header {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    #myUL li a {
        border: 1px solid #141414;
        margin-top: -1px;
        /* Prevent double borders */
        background-color: #8A8A8A;
        padding: 7px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block
    }

    #myUL li a.header {
        background-color: #454545;
        cursor: default;
    }

    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
        background-color: #525252;
    }
</style>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="#https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hmJ2cUx8GFc/V8WyozvS_KI/AAAAAAAAAO0/E_mnK1gELu0YMudfgDXt5w1VDj9103cegCLcB/s1600/merengue.jpg" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"> <img border="0" height="162" alt="Merengue" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hmJ2cUx8GFc/V8WyozvS_KI/AAAAAAAAAO0/E_mnK1gELu0YMudfgDXt5w1VDj9103cegCLcB/s320/merengue.jpg" width="320" /></a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"> <br />
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="myInputBorde"> <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Introducir nombre de cantante"> </div>
        <ul id="myUL">
            <!-- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">A</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Alex Bueno</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Amarfis</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Angelito Villalona</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Aramis Camilo</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">B</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Benny Sadel</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Big Swing</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Bonny Cepeda</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">C</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Charlie Rodriguez</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Cheche Abreu</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Cherito</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Chiqui Rodriguez</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Chuky Acosta</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Coco Band</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Cuco Valoy</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">D</a></li>
            <!-- EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">E</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">El Jeffrey</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">El Zafiro</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Elvis Crespo</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">F</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Fausto Rey</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Felix Cumbe</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Fenix Ortiz</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Fernando Villalona</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">G</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Hector Acosta</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Grupo Tambo</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Grupo Mania</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">H</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Henry Garcia</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Henry Hierro</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">I</a></li>
            <!-- JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">J</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Jacubanda</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Joseph Fonseca</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Jossie Esteban</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">July Mateo Rasputin</a></span></b> </li>
            <!-- KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">K</a></li>
            <!-- LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">L</a></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">La Gran Manzana</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">La Linea</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">La Makina</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">La Orquesta Joven</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Las Chicas del Can</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Lokera</a></b></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-size: large;"><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Hermanos Rosarios</a></b></span></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Hijos de Puerto Rico</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Kenton</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Potros</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Sabrosos del Merengue</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Los Toros Band</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">M</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Manny Manuel</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Miram Cruz</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">N</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Nelson Cordero El Varon</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">O</a></li>
            <!-- PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">P</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Peña Suazo</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Peter Cruz</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Popurri Clasico</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">Q</a></li>
            <!-- RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">R</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Raffy Matias</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ramon Orlando</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ray Polanco</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Rubby Perez</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">S</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Sandy Reyes</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Sergio Vargas</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">T</a></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Tempo Dominicano</a></span></b></li>
            <li><b><span style="font-size: large;"><a href="#" target="_blank">Toño Rosario</a></span></b></li>
            <!-- UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">U</a></li>
            <!-- VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">V</a></li>
            <!-- WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">W</a></li>
            <li><b><a href="#" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: large;">Wilfrido Vargas</span></a></b></li>
            <!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">X</a></li>
            <!-- YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">Y</a></li>
            <!-- ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ -->
            <li><a href="##" class="header">Z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is the following, I create an entry or a page in html, I give the option to treat it purely as html, when I add the entry using the permanent link and in the blog I click to access that section the page Has the new link in the url, but what it shows is the home page without any change

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve blog pages by using Blog Posts widget in your template. To do this you need to [create a section](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969) (a section can only contain widgets) then include Blog Posts widget in your section.

```
<!-- Section -->
<b:section id='main' class='main' showaddelement='yas'>

  <!-- Blog posts widget -->
  <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' version='1' visible='true'></b:widget>

</b:section>
```

You can also use [blogger conditional tags](http://www.codiblog.com/2016/09/blogger-conditional-tags.html) to targeting diffrent page types.